# python output without a lot spacing

Tags: python

[this is the output when i run the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R39cH.png)I am having issues completing my code i am working on in python. Basically i am cleaning up a string and i am able to achieve my aim. but the output doesn't give me the necessary result. so the string has a lot of \n characters in it. bear in mind, i need to print out line by line but the spacing i get after each output print is the problem.

The code :

```
x = "\n\n\n\nE\n\n\n\n\n                                        2003 Acura Mdx\n
```

This is what i have done below:

```
for char in '" ",':  
x = x.replace(char,'')
print(x)
```

this is the output:

E

2003AcuraMdx

NigerianUsed

₦561000

Mileage:219410Km

Year:2003

CarID:NG-445768

Onitsha-SNB
Onitsha

Comment: What is the output you want to get?

Comment: Do you mean something along the lines of `x = re.sub(r'\n+', '\n', x)`??

Comment: I agree with @JvdV here, if you want to replace multiple characters go with `re.sub()`, it's the most powerful, maybe also `strip()` from `string` will bring you where you want to be. Some more information on the desired output would be needed though to help properly.

Comment: i have added an image of the output for more clarity.